# How do I include a video in metatags through my wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress, loops, meta-tags, oembed

I'm trying to use this code to ask if the post is a video if so it would add the video meta-tags needed to display a playable video on facebook. The result is that it dosnt call the_content(); an example post from my site: http://associate.graymafia.com/old-spice-remix/

```
<?php if( get_post_format() == 'video' ) {
echo '<meta property="og:video" content="';
the_content();
echo '" />'; 
echo        '<meta property="og:video:height" content="640" />';
echo        '<meta property="og:video:width" content="385" />';
echo        '<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />';


} else {


} ?>
```

The content is just the url of the video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`the_content()` is a WordPress core function and is used to echo out the whole HTML of the post, and can only be used inside the loop. What you want in your og:video meta tag instead is your video's URL. If you have defined your own function `the_content()` then you just need to rename it.